# Flush left alignment in scientific paper

Tags: flalign

I am using `flalign` function but apparently, my output is right aligned. Why is this happening?

I want everything under variable; staring from the left side of the page. How can I do it?

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
    \begin{subequations}
\begin{flalign}
\mathbf{variables:}\\
\mathbf{S}_{g_i} \in \mathbb{C}^{|\phi_{i}|},
\mathbf{W}_{ii}  \in \mathbb{H}^{|\phi_{i}|\times|\phi_{i}|} (\forall i \in N),\nonumber\\
\mathbf{W}_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}^{|\phi_{ij}|\times|\phi_{ij}|} (\forall i \sim j \in  E)\nonumber\\
\end{flalign}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the alignment point. If you don't, the alignment point are the end of lines. Furthermore, `flalign` requires at least two groups of alignment, so you need a second `&` to indicate there are two groups. Last observation: do not end your maths environment with a `\\`: this creates a new (empty) line, which will be numbered

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some more text. Some more text.. Some more text. Some more text.

 \begin{subequations}
\begin{flalign}
 & \mathbf{variables:} & \\
 & \mathbf{S}_{g_i} \in \mathbb{C}^{|\phi_{i}|},
  \mathbf{W}_{ii} \in \mathbb{H}^{|\phi_{i}|\times|\phi_{i}|} (\forall i \in N),\nonumber \\
 & \mathbf{W}_{ij} \in \mathbb{C}^{|\phi_{ij}|\times|\phi_{ij}|} (\forall i \sim j \in E)\nonumber
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]